# Why this web image url is valid only once and only within browser?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm trying to write a python script to automatically [renew fastssh account](https://www.fastssh.com/page/renew-ssh-account). On the renew page there is a captcha structured like this:

```
<label>
<img src='https://fastssh.com/images/temp/blablablabla1.jpg' >
X
<img src='https://fastssh.com/images/temp/blablablabla2.jpg' >
=
</label>
<input type="text" name="CaptchaPass" id="captcha"  required/>
```

So I need to determine the two numbers from the two `jpg`'s and do the arithmetic. To automate this process, I tried to fetch the `jpg`'s with following code:

```
 import requests, sys
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 url = 'https://www.fastssh.com/page/renew-ssh-account'
 s = requests.session()
 text = s.get(url).text
 soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

 options = soup.find_all('option')
 found = False
 for option in options:
     if 'fr.serverip.co' in ''.join(option.contents):
         serverid = option['value']
         found = True
         break
 if not found:
     sys.exit('server not found.')

 captcha = soup.find(id='captcha')
 imgTag2 = captcha.find_previous('img')
 img2 = s.get(imgTag2['src'], stream=True)

 with open('num2.jpg', 'wb') as out:
     for block in img2.iter_content(1024):
         if not block:
             break
         out.write(block)
```

However, `num2.jpg` wrote to disk at last is actually an `html` file!

Also I found that if I use a my chrome browser to load the [renew page](https://www.fastssh.com/page/renew-ssh-account), manually copy & paste the `jpg` url from html source code to a new tab and hit enter, it actually redirects me to the homepage, which I believe is what I got in `num2.jpg` above.

I think this might have something to do with cookie? But shouldn't session in `requests` package take care of all necessary cookies?

Comment: Yes, `requests` takes care of cookies. So your diagnosis is not correct, it is not (just) cookies.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's wired that if I use Chrome's developer tools, I can see two more cookies except `PHPESSID` that I can't see with `requests`. These two are `_ga` and `_gat`. If I use FireFox, I could see `__asc` and `__auc`, which I can't see even using Chrome.

Comment: Take into account that those cookies could have been set by another page, or at some point in the past. Use a *private session* (incognito, private browsing, whatever the feature of the specific browser is called) to start out with no cookies, and look for Set-Cookie headers.

Comment: But *also* look at the other headers. It could be that the User-Agent is being parsed by the server, for example. The server is a black box, we cannot know its inner workings, but you *can* observe the inputs here. Just take into account all possible inputs.